# Importing couple methods as different objects

Tags: python, import

How can I f.e. import search and match from re module as re_match and re_search properly?

```
from re import match, search as re_match, re_match
```

This doesn't work

Comment: Rather than *"this doesn't work"*, it's generally helpful to be more specific - in this case, providing the full error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

You have the order wrong and a duplicate name; your current attempt is interpreted as

```
from re import (match), (search as re_match), (re_match)
```

hence the error - `re_match` isn't in `re`. You want

```
from re import match as re_match, search as re_search
```

Although this saves nothing over `re.match` and `re.search`, so it's not clear why you'd bother!

Answer (score -1):

The reason this isn't working is because you can't import both of these things using `as` and defining them as the same alias. You need different aliases. The following would work:

```
from re import match as re_match
from re import search as re_search
```

note the difference in aliases.

Furthermore, if you use the `as` keyword, these commands need to be on separate lines. This is because Python interprets comma-delimited lists as tuples, and attempts to unpack them. If you want them on the same line, you need to do them separately, such as:

```
from re import match as re_match, search as re_search
```

Comment: You *can* import both to the same alias, if you get the order right, although obviously you can then only access one of them!

Comment: Yeah I did a ninja-edit to my answer that says it's because of the way python is unpacking his tuples. However, the same alias would cause issues in the future, so I feel this is important to mention.